# What is wrong with the MySQL syntax I am using?

Tags: mysql, syntax, local

As far as I can tell I have done nothing wrong here, especially when compared with the syntax of other .sql files I have run on my local MySQL server prior to this.

This screenshot shows the .sql file and my attempt to run the file in MySQL.

[image]
[image]

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Please copy your SQL script into the question.  Having to look at it as an uneditable image is quite a pain.

Comment: The whole thing is quite long, should I paste a small segment?

Edit: I put it on pastebin to keep this thread tidy, does that help?
 http://pastebin.com/72uEZW7P

Comment: . . If it is quite long, that would make it all the more useful as text that can be edited and scrolled, wouldn't it?

Comment: You're totally right, I'll make sure I include the raw text next time

Comment: Have placed relevant parts of the (rather large) image directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number` is not a valid data type in MySQL. Use one of the Integer types. `VARCHAR2()` is also invalid - use `VARCHAR()`

Although it is syntactically correct, don't use `FLOAT` for money values - it loses precision and you can get errors in basic arithmetic. Use `DECIMAL` for cash values.

You can find the complete reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: So to follow this up, I went through and have tried to fix as much of my script as possible, especially regarding date values. I get considerably fewer errors now than I did previously, but I still get some. Here is my updated script: http://pastebin.com/LG9tBwPT and here are the errors I am getting: http://i.imgur.com/joTzCVK.png If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it! (EDIT: some of my date values are still wrong, will fix and update now)

Comment: Here is the updated script file: http://pastebin.com/MCDP2a6q - the errors I receive are the same as before. (I changed the file again, so the Primary Key for each table is identified on a separate line in the Create Table statement. I don't think it's had an impact though)

Comment: You're missing a comma after the `GCostChild` field in your first `Create Table` statement. That statement works on my tes server, but there may be other errors elsewhere. The MySQL reference for `CREATE` is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html). Check your statements carefully, and then I suggest you execute each `CREATE` one at a time, fixing any syntax problems until you have them all done. Likewise with the `INSERT` statements

Answer (score 1):

Use `INT(3)` instead of `NUMBER(3)` and `VARCHAR(20)` instead of `VARCHAR2(20)`

Answer (score 1):

Your data types are incorrect - NUMBER and VARCHAR2 do not exist. Have a look at the MySQL manual chapter on [Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html).

On a side note, it's best to keep case-sensitivity with table names. It's doesn't matter on Windows, but should you ever move your code to a UNIX environment it would be a pain to fix!

Comment: This is very interesting. This database is one I made a few months ago as a piece of coursework and it worked fine. That may have been an Oracle or some other kind of SQL server, though, and I just thought all the SQL types would be compatible. Thanks a lot, +1'ed.

I also fixed the different cases after I posted my question here just to make sure that wasn't the problem. As you said, since I'm on Windows it made no difference but I'll make sure to keep it up as a matter of good practice in the future.

Comment: Just because the DBMS uses SQL does not mean it uses a common set of data types! I image you were indeed using an Oracle database - those types are valid in that context.